# report.CRITICAL: Empty or no Private Key provided [] []

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.4

After the upgrade from M2.3.3 to M2.4.2 checkout page is not working.

In system.log file I am getting an error:

> [2021-04-27 10:35:21] report.CRITICAL: Empty or no Private Key provided [] []

Anyone having idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little to no details to go on on based on your error, alas with some googling I've ended up at this exception:

https://github.com/open-pay/openpay-php/blob/master/data/OpenpayApiConnector.php#L45

```php
   $myApiKey = Openpay::getApiKey();
   if (!$myApiKey) {
       throw new OpenpayApiAuthError("Empty or no Private Key provided");
   } else if (!preg_match('/^sk_[a-z0-9]{32}$/i', $myApiKey)) {
       throw new OpenpayApiAuthError("Invalid Private Key '".$myApiKey."'");
   }
```

Which I suppose indicates you're using a module to interact with OpenPay's API ( [maybe this one?](https://github.com/open-pay/openpay-magento2-cards) ) in which case you may wanna double-check your private key are all sorted out in your back-end config:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.After upgrading to Magento 2.4.2 my openpay module seems to be different.Paths are creating like app\code\Openpay\Banks\Block\Block\Block\Onepage & I think this is wrong. Please suggest the ways to resolve this. Also do I need to check backend configuration as well ? Please guide asap